# P2SH to LTC address with M

Tags: litecoin, p2sh, p2pkh

Are there anyone know how to convert P2SH address (like `34A5PyCvPJKYtHmj9jmKhGzBBwpGuAkZog`) to `MANDhrctLRAygo3dFckfWvEaWeQizSwWNK`?

I tried to decode with `Base58Check`, then removed `05` and added  `032`, then encode it (`Base58Check`), however I got wrong result `MANDhrctLRAygo3dFckfWvEaWeQiti143C`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting a different address is because you are appending the same checksum that you got from using the `03` prefix to the new `prefix + payload`. You need to double hash the new `prefix + payload` and then append the first four bytes and then encode it in base58.

If I decode your result `MANDhrctLRAygo3dFckfWvEaWeQiti143C` to hexadecimal, I get `321b0e61ac671bde7fb52e2f3d6e2dc213609d9de5020cb31b`. In this hexadecimal string, your prefix is `32`, payload is `1b0e61ac671bde7fb52e2f3d6e2dc213609d9de5`, and checksum is `020cb31b`.

The checksum that you would get after double hashing the new `prefix + payload` is `e29f4248`. So, you should base58 encode `321b0e61ac671bde7fb52e2f3d6e2dc213609d9de5e29f4248`